# Changing item colors individually in BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

I am looking for a way to programatically change my item colors in my `BottomNavigationView`.

I found out how to change icons color, i did it as following :

```
fun setMenu(selected: Int) {
    bottomNavigationMenu?.let {
        it.menu.findItem(R.id.bottom_menu_home).icon
                .setColorFilter(getMenuColor(R.id.bottom_menu_home, selected), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
        // more items
        it.menu.findItem(R.id.bottom_menu_fidelity)?.icon
                ?.setColorFilter(getMenuColor(R.id.bottom_menu_fidelity, selected), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
    }
}

fun getMenuColor(id: Int, selected: Int): Int {
    if (Singletons.restaurant.title.isBlank())
        getRestaurant()
    else {
        if (id == selected) return (Singletons.restaurant.color)
        else return ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.grey7E)
    }
    return (0)
}
```

Now I am looking for how to change the title color.
I am looking for something like

```
it.menu.findItem(R.id.bottom_menu_home).title // etc
```

but I can't find a correct function to do it.

Here is my items from *main_bottom_menu.xml* :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/bottom_menu_home"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:iconTint="@color/cardview_dark_background"
        android:title="@string/bottom_menu_home"
        android:visible="false"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <!-- 3 more items -->

    <item
        android:id="@+id/bottom_menu_profile"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile"
        android:iconTint="@color/cardview_dark_background"
        android:title="@string/bottom_menu_profile"
        android:visible="false"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

Oddly, the text color is equal to my `colorPrimary`, so it has to be set somewhere.
The goal is to dynamically set a color (from an API).
Any idea of where was my title color set ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To set the color of all items, you could simply call [`setItemTextColor()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html#setItemTextColor(android.content.res.ColorStateList)) on your `BottomNavigationView` instance.

To set them individually, you could use a `SpannableString`:

```
val titleSpannable = SpannableString("title")

titleSpannable.setSpan(
    ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#ffffff")),
    0,
    titleString.length,
    Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)

bottomNavigationView.menu.findItem(R.id.your_item_id).title = titleSpannable
```